# Will a process writing to a pipe block if the pipe is full?

Tags: c, winapi, pipe, createprocess

I'm currently diving into the Win32 API and writing myself a wrapper class for `CreateProcess` and `CreatePipe`. I was just wondering what will happen if a process that I opened writes too much output for the pipe buffer to hold. Will the process wait until I read from the other end of the pipe? The Remark of the `CreatePipe` function suggests so:

> When a process uses WriteFile to write to an anonymous pipe, the write operation is not completed until all bytes are written. If the pipe buffer is full before all bytes are written, WriteFile does not return until another process or thread uses ReadFile to make more buffer space available.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Let's assume I open a process with `CreateProcess`, then use `WaitForSingleObject` to wait until the process exits. Will the process ever exit if it exceeds the buffer size of its standard output pipe?

Comment: If the official reference says that the `WriteFile` function "does not return until..." that is the same as it blocking. So then the answer is that yes writing to a full pipe will block. By the way, it's standard behavior on e.g. POSIX systems (like Linux or OSX) as well.

Comment: In POSIX systems this is indeed what happens: the producer is blocked until there is space to write into. For instance, when you do `ls -R / | less`, `less` will read some screens of text and then block `ls`, until the user scrolls down. If the user kills the reader process (e.g. by quitting `less`), the original process will be killed. This can save a lot of useless computations.

Comment: "Does not return" == block.  If you don't read redirected output then, yes, the process is highly likely to deadlock.   A pretty standard bug is to drain stdout but not stderr.   You'll need WaitForMultipleObjects() on all 3 handles.

Comment: @HansPassant If the process exits, won't the outputs be closed, so you can just read the output pipe(s) without also including the process? And can you leave stderr on the console so it's not your problem?

Comment: @Random832: Sure you can leave `stderr` tied to a console stream.  Or both `stdout` and `stderr` to the same pipe.

Comment: Usually, yes.  Beware the race, process exit happens later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WaitForSingleObject` on a process with redirected output is indeed a deadlock.  You need to keep the output pipe drained in order to let the child process run to completion.

Generally you would use overlapped I/O on the pipe and then `WaitForMultipleObjects` on the handle pair<sup>1</sup> (process handle, pipe read event handle) in a loop until the process handle becomes signaled.

Raymond Chen wrote about the scenario when the input is also piped:

- [Be careful when redirecting both a process's stdin and stdout to pipes, for you can easily deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx)

---

<sup>1</sup> As Hans commented, there can be more than one output stream.  `stdout`, `stderr` are typical, even more are possible through handle inheritance.  Drain all the pipes coming out of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. I have still one question: When I call `CloseHandle` on all pipes created for the process, could the deadlock still happen or am I safe to call `WaitForSingleObject`? I want to add a `Wait()` method that will simply omit any output produced by the process but block until it terminates.

Comment: Are you asking about CloseHandle is the parent or child process? That will prevent deadlock, but the other end of the pipe will experience errors when it tries to write or zero byte reads.

Comment: In the parent process. With "handles in the child process", are you referring to the handles I specified in the `STARTUPINFO` structure? Assuming the child process reads from the standard input and I close it from the parent process, will the child process run into an error or will it just read nothing (or what's left) in the standard input pipe?

Comment: @NiklasR: If the write end of a pipe is closed, the read end will start returning zero-length reads.  Which should be recognized as an "end-of-file" condition.